# how can i run a script from Android.mk and read it's exit code (return value)

Tags: android, shell, compilation

I'm running a shell script from Android.mk which does some copying and stuff, and I want to read the return value that the script returns, if it fails, I want to halt the compilation.

```
$(shell $(LOCAL_PATH)/makescript.sh)
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
value = ./makescript.sh
if value = 1 halt compilation of Android.mk file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you'd like to achieve, this should work:

```
ifeq (1,$(shell $(LOCAL_PATH)/makescript.sh))
$(error your error message.)
endif
```

And if you want to do it in the assign-value way,

```
return_val := $(shell $(LOCAL_PATH)/makescript.sh)
ifeq (1, $(return_val))
$(error your error message.)
endif
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run your script as a normal process and get  the input stream  that is returned b y your script.

```
    try{
        Process proccess = new ProcessBuilder( )
            .command( "path to yur script file" )
            .redirectErrorStream( true )
            .start();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( proccess.getInputStream() );
        in.close();
    }catch( IOException ioe ){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you missed the point here, I want it part of the compilation, if the script fails, the android.mk compilation should declare failure and stop.